# Conditional Sql in Daisy chained Query

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, join, conditional-statements

I have one master table with all the IDs to each child table. The SQL statement looks like this...

```
SELECT   Class.Descript
       , Regulation.Descript AS Reg
       , Compgroup.Descript AS Grouping
       , Category.Descript AS Cat
       , Exempt.Descript AS Exempt
       , Reason.Descript AS Reasons
       , COALESCE(ComponentRuleSet.NormalType, ComponentRuleSet.Supertype, '') AS Type
FROM     ComponentRuleSet 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reason 
   ON ComponentRuleSet.ComponentCategoryID = Reason.ComponentCategoryID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Class 
   ON ComponentRuleSet.ComponentClassID = Class.ComponentClassID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Regulation
   ON ComponentRuleSet.RegulationID = Regulation.RegulationID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Compgroup
   ON ComponentRuleSet.ComplianceGroupID = Compgroup.ComplianceGroupID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category 
   ON ComponentRuleSet.ComponentCategoryID = Category.ComponentCategoryId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Exempt 
   ON ComponentRuleSet.ExemptID = Exempt.ComponentExemptionID
WHERE (ComponentRuleSet.ComponentID = 38048)
```

The problem is that there are two fields in the **ComponentRuleSet** table called **NormalType** and **Supertype**. If either of those fields have a value, I need to display it in a column called **Type**. Yet, if neither have a value I need to display a Blank value in the **Type** column. 
Any ideas?

---EDIT

Is my placement of COALESCE correct in the edited query? It is still returning errors.

--UPDATE

IMPORTANT: The type of both fields are boolean, I need to return the column name of the column that holds a TRUE value, and place that value in the TYPE column.

Comment: What do you do if _both_ have a value?

Comment: It has to be one type or the other. ON/OFF switch concept. Values from both fields is not possible.

Comment: I assumed as much, but wanted confirmation, as you did not mention that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your comments, perhaps a `CASE` expression will work:

```
select ...
      , CASE WHEN ComponentRuleSet.NormalType is not null then 'NormalType'
             WHEN ComponentRuleSet.Supertype  is not null then 'SuperType'
             ELSE ''
             end as Type
```

**UPDATE** Since boolean values are just 1 for true and 0 for false, try this:

```
select ...
      , CASE WHEN ComponentRuleSet.NormalType = 1 then 'NormalType'
             WHEN ComponentRuleSet.Supertype  = 1 then 'SuperType'
             ELSE ''
             end as Type
```

Comment: Would this not cause conflict if NormalType was TRUE and SuperType was FALSE. SuperType would not be NULL

Comment: The type of both fields are boolean.

Comment: @Ccorock - Just change the expression to however you would select "TRUE".  I don't know the data type of the two columns and was guessing.

Comment: Extremely helpful, Thank you! I wish I could mark two answers for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) for this field:

```
COALESCE(ComponentRuleSet.NormalType, ComponentRuleSet.Supertype, '') AS Type
```

`COALESCE`:

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

---

Following your comments as to the actual requirement, [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is probably a better option:

```
CASE WHEN ComponentRuleSet.NormalType = 1 THEN 'NormalType'
     WHEN ComponentRuleSet.Supertype = 1 THEN 'SuperType'
     ELSE ''
END AS Type
```

Comment: @Ccorock - Um. I did include that bit... I am using an alias (`AS Type` at the end).

Comment: Im afraid I need the actual column name that the True statement is in. For example IF ComponentRuleSet.Supertype = True then Type's value will = SuperType.

Comment: You should put your comments and questions beneath the Answer, not on the Question.  That said, what error did you get using `COALESCE`?  My guess is that you need a different column name: `TYPE` might be a reserved word.

Comment: The syntax is correct now. The only problem now is the functionality. Read above comment.

Comment: @Ccorock - `If either of those fields have a value, I need to display it in a column called Type`. That's what `COALESCE` does - it uses that value. It wasn't clear these are boolean nullable fields and that you need `Type` to be `SuperType`, `NormalType` or `NULL`. Is my understanding now correct?

Comment: My apologies for the miscommunication. Your statement above is correct. These are boolean fields and within Type I need to display either SuperType or NormalType.

Comment: @Ccorock - Please confirm the data type of `SuperType` and `NormalType`.

Comment: The type of both fields are Boolean.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for answering my original question.